# xproj file not available in my vs2015 website?

Tags: visual-studio, typescript, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, .net-core

I created a new Empty Website in VS2015. I read that VS2015 now uses a new xproj file as opposed to the traditional csproj file to maintain project references.  However, the new website I created has a csproj file but no xproj file.  Was the xproj file type introduced in a later update of VS2015?  Or is Empty Website considered a legacy or different type of project that VS creates with a csproj as opposed to an xproj?

Answer (score 1):

The .xproj file type (along with project.json) basically replaces the previous .csproj file types that you would find within .NET applications.

Much like the .csproj file that handled managing everything that was included in your project (and generally lots of other stuff like build operations, etc.), the .xproj file and project.json files will essentially do the same thing (it was introduced within .NET Core).

In terms of ASP.NET website, you need to have ASP.NET 5 template which now renamed as ASP.NET core 1.0

Refer below image.

[image]

This is from VS 2015 community edition Update 3 with ASP.NET 5 templates.

Hope this helps.